# javascript - Copying div content from another document

Tags: javascript, html, copy, document

I have a small website with a mobile and desktop index page. I'd like to be able to edit only one of the index pages, and have the mobile version be generated by "coping" the contents of the desktop page. This way I can simplify my workflow.

How would I go about copying an entire div's content from one html document to another?

Comment: I suggest using cone jquery api

Comment: This will increase the overhead for the devices with less overhead, instead create a 3rd place which keeps your content, and have the moble/desktop html generated from it

Comment: Are you asking about using ajax to load in HTML? Or are you asking about making a build script to copy content?

Comment: Sounds like he's asking to create a hidden `iframe` to contain the source of alternative content, but this requires moving nodes between documents. See my answer for more information.

Comment: Actually, I would need to import only a single div, and would prefer if the contents could be transferred into a new div, instead of an iframe. Does .importNode() still sound like my best option?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could set up some script to run some regex, copying the elements from one to the other after making edits on your doc each time.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use `.appendChild()` to move an element around the document, but this does not permit moving elements between documents. For that, you would need `.importNode()` (creating a copy) or `.adoptNode()` (removing it from the original document first).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode for documentation and examples. Additionally, make sure you read the browser compatibility notes at the bottom.

If you are making a copy within the same document and want to keep the original, you can use `.cloneNode()` before `.appendChild()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode